# Vimeo: how to use php official client to add a domain whitelist for a video?

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using official Vimeo PHP client.

I can upload a video, and set `privacy.embed` to `whitelist`.

Then doc tells me:

> To add a domain to the whitelist, send a `PUT` request to `/videos/{video_id}/privacy/domains/{domain}`.

I tried

```
$privacy_uri = $uri . "/privacy/domains/testdomain.tld";
$domain_add_response = $client->request($privacy_uri);
```

where
- `$uri` is the `/vimeo/<video_id>`
- `$client`  is born from `new Vimeo(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VIMEO_TOKEN);`

### Problem

Printing the `$domain_add_response` I get a `405` error, probably because of `Allow` (see the following response dump)

```
Array
(
    [body] => 
    [status] => 405
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Server] => nginx
            [Content-Type] => application/json
            [Allow] => PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
            [X-Vimeo-DC] => ge
            [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
            [Via] => 1.1 varnish
            [Content-Length] => 0
            [Date] => Mon, 15 Apr 2019 08:30:47 GMT
            [Connection] => keep-alive
            [X-Served-By] => cache-bwi5125-BWI, cache-mxp19820-MXP
            [X-Cache] => MISS, MISS
            [X-Cache-Hits] => 0, 0
            [X-Timer] => S1555317047.232635,VS0,VE148
            [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
        )

)
```

I imagine I must set the `PUT`  method in my request, but ... how ?

Comment: Do you use CURL for requests? Can you show us the code that makes the request?

Comment: It's not the code that makes the request.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa: `$domain_add_response = $client->request($privacy_uri);` is the exact code making the request !

Comment: And how do we know what `->request` method does and what parameters accepts ?

Comment: $client, as stated in the question, is the official Vimeo php client. The source code is here: `https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L88`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found looking at api source code: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L88

where the signature of `request` is

```
public function request($url, $params = array(), $method = 'GET', $json_body = true, array $headers = array()): array
```

I understand that I can fix the problem, simply passing an empty `$params` array and specifing `PUT` as request `$method`

I changed this line

```
$domain_add_response = $client->request($privacy_uri);
```

Into this form

```
$domain_add_response = $client->request($privacy_uri, [], 'PUT');
```

And it works as expected